# Discrete Uniform Law

Tags: probability

[image: discrete uniform law]

Edit:
How do I fit the examples provided into the framework of $N$, $m$?

It's from the MIT open courseware here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/resources/lecture-1-video/
Edit:

[image: with times m]

Comment: What's wrong with the examples they provide (fair coins, fair dice, well-shuffled decks)?

Comment: @lulu I added a photo that multiplies with $m$.  Say with coins, I have $N=2$ then with $m=2$? since the elements are {heads, tails}?  Then the probability is $\frac{1}{N} * m$?  so $\frac{1}{2} * 2 = \frac{2}{2} = 1$?  What are $A$ and $P(A)$?  Is $A$ heads and its complement $A^c$ tails?  I just don't know how to fit one of the examples into that framework.

Comment: There are two outcomes when you toss a fair coin.  $H$ and $T$.  That's it.  They are equally likely.  The letter $A$ here just stands for a possible event.  One of the outcomes, for example, or some combination of these outcomes.  If, say, you are tossing a fair die, $A$ might be the event "you throw an even number".

Comment: What are the elements then and why does $\frac{1}{N} * m = 1$ then assuming $m=2$ for heads and tails?

Comment: Pick an example.  Let's do the fair die.  Then there are $6$ possible outcomes, each with probability $\frac 16$.  Those are your core events.  If, as in my comment, we take $A$ to be the event "you roll an even number", then $A$ is comprised of $3$ outcomes...namely $2,4,6$.  Thus your numerator is $3$.  Your denominator is, of course, $6$ as there are $6$ possible outcomes in total.  Thus $P(A)=\frac 36=\frac 12$.

Comment: Note:  I switched from the fair coin to the fair die because there really aren't many events one can speak of when dealing with a fair coin.  Working with the die allows us to consider more interesting combinations of outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

Consider the scenario that there are $N$ balls with different colors of which $m$  of them are red balls.

The probability of drawing a red ball would be $\frac{m}{N}$.

Comment: I get it, so $m$ is the number of target outcomes and $N$ is the number of all outcomes.  Why do they call $m$ elements?

Comment: element as in element of a set.